# Форматирование вывода в консоль, отображение степени

Tags: java

Каким способом можно отформатировать вывод, чтобы заданное число отображалось как степень ?
Примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависит в какой кодировке консоль, если в utf-8, то можно

Comment: @sercxjo, да ...кодировка в utf-8!!!
Как можно это сделать ???

Comment: Если utf8, тогда уже и зведочки на нормальное умножение надо менять

Answer (score 10):

Вот символы ² ³ ¹ ⁰ ⁱ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁴ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ⁿ

Вот [один из вариантов](http://foxtools.ru/Unicode), где можно найти их коды.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго дня!

У вас файл в котором написан код должен находится в кодировке UTF-8 и тогда используя спец символы можно в коде написать так:

```
System.out.println("1*10² + 2*10¹ + 3*10⁰");
```

Comment: а какой спецсимвол ?? С таблицы кодировки символов UTF-8 ???

Comment: Да. Можете скопировать из моего ответа, или из ответа выше